# Chart loading when changing window size

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm creating a chart using chart.js, when I open the web page the chart is there but the data only loads when I resize the window after a few seconds. I assume its something to do with the asynchronous functions but i'm not sure?

Here is my code

```
    let xlabels = [];
    let ydata = [];
    
    chartIt();
    
    async function chartIt(){
        await getData();
        const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: xlabels,
                datasets:[{
                   data: ydata
                }],
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    async function getData(){
        fetch('/test')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
            
        })
        .then(function (text){
    
        for(var i= 0; i < text.length; ++i){
            const date = text[i].date;
            xlabels.push(date);
            const mass=text[i].mass;
            ydata.push(mass);
        }
        });
    }
```

Comment: at the end of the fetch try calling update on your chart

Comment: @LeeLenalee I have tried adding chartIt.update(); after the for loop, is this what you meant? as this did not work